# How to pause or resume a web call (ie, file download)

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

My application is having a requirement like pause or resume a we call(downloading a file). In my application I need to call a set of Urls sequentially or parallelly and I have to get the time taken to finish the call. It has an option to pause and resume while calling a url. How can I achieve it. I tried Async Task but it does not have pause and resume option. If anybody have an idea please help me for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pause/resume one web service call: HTTP protocol simply does not support it.  You can try playing with HTTP/1.1 keep-alive connection, but that may be rather painful and I would strongly advise against it.  Instead, what you should do is pause between URL calls.  That is, make one call, retrieve data, then either go to the next one or pause before going to the next one.

You can simply achieve this with `AsyncTask`.  In your class declare a `boolean` variable to keep run state (pause/run) and an `indicator` member variable of type `Object` - you'll need it for notifications.

Then in your `doInBackground` method loop over your URL's calling each one sequentially.  When you completed one call, check that variable.  If it's set to `false` (i.e. `pause` has been called), then wait until it's set to true - with something like this:

```
for(each url in your list) {
    //make the call and retrieve the data
    ....
    if(!this.runState) { //pause has been called
        // the below code blocks until notified
        synchronized(indicator) {
            try {
                runState.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Nothing needs to be done here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you will need stop/resume methods:

```
public synchronized void pause() {
    runState = false;
}

public synchronized void resume() {
    runState = true;
    //this code notifies the process (in the loop) to stop waiting
    synchronized(syncObject) {
        indicator.notify();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to stop and resume a file download using HTTP, then there are two things you need to do.

1. Handle InputStream from the connection manually, reading, say, 1024 bytes at a time. Keep track of how much you're read in total.  After each read check that the "pause" hasn't been called. If it has, then wait until the "resume" has been called.
2. When resume has been called, attempt to continue reading the stream.  If the stream has been closed by the server end, then re-establish connection and specify the offset using `Range` HTTP header, e.g. `Range: bytes=4096-` will request that the server resumes transfer from byte 4096 onward of the stream.  Note that not all servers support this header.  If your particular server does not, then you're out of luck.

The actual pause/resume/check logic would be the same as described above.

Comment: sorry to say that, this web call is actually a file url and it is getting downloaded(a small sized file).

Comment: @AjuVidyadharan I updated my answer with a bit more details on that scenario

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I looked at the HTTP protocol*, but iirc you can set a parameter to indicate an offset in the output stream.  This would let you 'resume' a download from where it previously stopped.  Obviously, this requires the server to support this feature.

*there is a possibility that I am getting mixed up with the FTP protocol as well.